# python3でインデックス参照エラー

Tags: python, python3

英単語を複数形にするプログラムです

インプットは

```
7
box
photo
axis
dish
church
leaf
knife
```

です。

```
input_line = int(input())
words_spell=[list(input()) for i in range(input_line)]



for i in range(input_line):
    #s, sh, ch, o, x は末尾にes
    if words_spell[i][-1]=="s" or words_spell[i][-1]=="o" or words_spell[i][-1]=="x" or words_spell[i][-2]+words_spell[i][-1]=="sh" or words_spell[i][-2]+words_spell[i][-1]=="ch":
        words_spell[i].append("es")
    #末尾が f, fe のいずれかである英単語の末尾の f, fe を除き、末尾に ves を付ける
    elif words_spell[i][-1]=="f" :
        del words_spell[-1]
        words_spell[i].append("ves")
    elif words_spell[i][-1]+words_spell[i][-2]=="fe":
        del words_spell[-2:-1]
        words_spell[i].append("ves")

    #末尾の1文字が y で、末尾から2文字目が a, i, u, e, o のいずれでもない英単語の末尾の y を除き、末尾に ies を付ける
    elif words_spell[i][-1]=="y" and words_spell[i][-2]!="a" and words_spell[i][-2]!= "i" and words_spell[i][-2]!="u" and words_spell[i][-2]!="e" and words_spell[i][-2]!="o":
        del words_spell[i][-1]
        words_spell[i].append("ies")

    #上のいずれの条件にも当てはまらない英単語の末尾には s を付ける
    else:
        words_spell[i].append("s")
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 12, in <module>
    if words_spell[i][-1]=="s" or words_spell[i][-1]=="o" or words_spell[i][-1]=="x" or words_spell[i][-2]+words_spell[i][-1]=="sh" or words_spell[i][-2]+words_spell[i][-1]=="ch":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

エラーの理由がわかりません。
ちなみにもう提出済みなのでカンニングではありません

Comment: `del words_spell[-1]` とかしてますけど、これって `del words_spell[i][-1]` ではないですかね。

Comment: そうですね！ただ、それとはちがうところでエラーになっていると思います。

Comment: あと、`del words_spell[-2:-1]` も `del words_spell[i][-2:-1]` なのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど！いま修正して動かしたらいい感じになりました！

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

エラーの原因についての質問なので回答にはなっていないのですが、Python では文字列型のオブジェクトにもスライス記法を使うことが可能です。また、

```
words_spell[i][-1]=="s" or words_spell[i][-1]=="o" or ...
```

などとしていますが、`endswith()` メソッドや `in`, `not in` 演算子を使うと読みやすく書くことができます。

```
# First line represents number of words
num_words = int(input())
# Take words
words = [input() for _ in range(num_words)]

# Pluralize
plurals = []
for w in words:
  # s, sh, ch, o, x は末尾にes
  if w.endswith(('s', 'sh', 'ch', 'o', 'x')):
    w += 'es'
  # 末尾が f, fe のいずれかである英単語の末尾の f, fe を除き、末尾に
  # ves を付ける
  elif w.endswith('f'):
    w = w[:-1] + 'ves'
  elif w.endswith('fe'):
    w = w[:-2] + 'ves'
  # 末尾の1文字が y で、末尾から2文字目が a, i, u, e, o のいずれでもない
  # 英単語の末尾の y を除き、末尾に ies を付ける
  elif w.endswith('y') and w[-2] not in ('a', 'i', 'u', 'e', 'o'):
    w = w[:-1] + 'ies'
  # 上のいずれの条件にも当てはまらない英単語の末尾には s を付ける
  else:
    w += 's'

  plurals.append(w)

print(plurals)
```

Comment: 勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！